# When moving files XCopy can put them into a file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, backup, xcopy

I was making a backup script for my usb and stumbled upon this.

```
xcopy "E:\" "D:\backup" /s/h/e/k/f/c/y
```

When I executed my batch script it created a file (not a folder) in my D:\ drive called backup.

Then I renamed it to a .zip folder and extracted it, it looked like this inside.

[image]

What are these files and what are they for?.

Am I able to backup my usb into a zip??.

Comment: That bears an uncanny resemblance to what you see when you open an Excel (.xlsx) file with archival software. Try opening the file with Excel and see what happens.

Comment: @Luke McGregor  try my answer below and see if that works

Answer (score 3):

Your video revealed on crucial bit of information that you left out of your initial question: when xcopy asked if your target destination was a file or a directory, you told xcopy that it was a file.

xcopy then proceeded to write every single file in your source to that file, because that's what you told it to do. Unfortunately, xcopy does not create archive files, so instead of merging all of your files into a container file, if simply overwrote the destination file with every single source file one at a time - this is the key to the strange behavior you're seeing.

According to your video, the very last file that xcopy processed was `Action Plan.xlsx` - this is important to note. Since that was the last file xcopy processed, D:\backup is a copy of that file and that file only.

The interesting thing about Excel files is that while the old .xls files were proprietary Microsoft files that could only be opened by Excel, the newer .xlsx files are really just archives of XML files. (For example, [this](http://i.imgur.com/HTOmJ2A.png) is what my work schedule from a few years ago looks like when you open it with WinRAR - look familiar?)

So in summary, you copied each file in your source to the same target file and the very last file your copied merely happened to be an archive file. Next time you run the script, pick **D** instead of **F**.

Comment: thanks for your answer that clears a lot up you my friend are very smart!! :)

Answer (score 1):

**"When moving files XCopy can put them into a file"**

`xcopy` **copies** files, it does not **move** them.

---

**"When I executed my batch script it created a file (not a folder) in my
D:\ drive called backup"**

You didn't already have a folder named `D:\backup`.

---

**"xcopy "E:\" "D:\backup" /s/h/e/k/f/c/y"**

Lets look at what the command options do.

- `/s` Copy folders and subfolders
- `/h` Copy hidden and system files and folders (default=N)
- `/e` Copy folders and subfolders, including Empty folders.
       can be used to modify /T.
- `/k` Copy attributes. XCOPY will otherwise reset read-only attributes
- `/f` Display full source and destination file names while copying.
- `/c` Continue copying even if an error occurs.
- `/y` Suppress prompt to confirm overwriting a file.

None of these options will make `xcopy` create a single file instead of a directory tree containing the copied files.

---

**"Then I renamed it to a .zip folder and extracted it,"**

See above. Why do you think the file is a zipfile? `xcopy` does not create zip files.

---

**"Am I able to backup my usb into a zip?"**

Yes, but not with `xcopy`. The windows `backup` command will create `zip` files behind the scenes.

See [How To Use Backup and Restore in Windows 7](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/1838/using-backup-and-restore-in-windows-7/) for more information.

Select the "Let me choose option" and choose your `E:` drive.

[image]

---

Source [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)

Comment: the reason why i asked this is not because it was giving errors bet because it seemed as if if was compressing them all together and saveing them to a file

Comment: "it seemed as if if was compressing them all together and saveing them to a file" -- As I explained in my answer this is not happening because of` `xcopy`. There must be something else going on that is not mentioned in your question.

Comment: `xcopy` does **not** create zip files.

Comment: uploading a video of what happens when the destination is a .zip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPJeP4NLg80&feature=youtu.be

Comment: "This video is private. Sorry about that.". In any case you said "When I executed my batch script it created a file (not a folder) in my D:\ drive called backup.". A created file called `backup` is not a zip file.

Comment: it is uploading the video try againg in around 20 min

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command and see if that works , ideally what i am trying to do is tell xcopy that artifact copied is a directory/folder and not a file

`echo D|xcopy "E:\" "D:\backup" /s/h/e/k/f/c/y`

Comment: So... exactly what I told him to do?

Comment: @SomethingDark agreed , missed your answer , similar to your's in coding style :)

Answer (score 0):

Run in a command prompt window `xcopy /?` and read help output for this command.

You can read there about parameter `/I` which tells **xcopy** that the target is a directory and not a file which should be created if not already existing. So all you need to do is appending to list of parameters `/i` or `/I`.

And I suggest to insert a space between each parameter as this is the common format, see help of command **xcopy**.